# Dynamic array as function argument

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, dynamic

In main function of my program I've created dynamic array with number of elements specified in variable(after calculations array is deleted):

```
cin >> bok;

double **macierz;
macierz = new double *[bok];
for(int i = 0; i < bok; ++i){
    macierz[i] = new double[bok];
}
```

Array *macierz* (matrix in Polish) is used to calculate it's determinant with another function I've written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

double determinant(double b[][bok],int m);

// there is int main(){ ... }

double determinant(double b[][bok],int m){

int i, j;
double sum = 0,

double **c;                 //Second array that throws "type 'double' unexpected"
c = new double *[m];
for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
    c[i] = new double[m];
}

if(m==2){
    sum = b[0][0]*b[1][1] - b[0][1]*b[1][0];
    return sum;
}

for(int p=0; p<m; p++){
    int h = 0,k = 0;
    for(i=1; i<m; i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            if(j==p)
                continue;
            c[h][k] = b[i][j];
            k++;
        if(k == m-1){
            h++;
            k = 0;
        }

        }
    }

sum = sum + b[0][p]*(pow((float)-1,p))*determinant(c,m-1);
}

for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){          //Removing second array
    delete[] c[i];
}
delete[] c;
return sum;
}
```

Here is the place in main function, where above one is used to calculate determinant:

```
    double det;
    det = determinant(macierz, bok);     //bok was entered by user
```

The problem is, that array *macierz* was created as dynamic, to allow user input number, which will be amount of array rows/columns (it's square matrix, so number of rows is equal to number of columns). It worked flawlessly until I've created function which needs this dynamic array as one of arguments.

How the declaration of *determinant* function should be modified to be able to use *macierz* array as it's first argument? And one more little thing - also array *c* in *determinant* function is throwing errors(it's next dynamic array, but I cannot understand, why it doesn't work - I've created and removed it like the *macierz* yet compiler is throwing "type 'double' unexpected")

Comment: Need a dynamic array use: `std::vector<double> obj;` Need a two dimensional array use `std::vector<std::vector<double>> obj;`

Comment: @AlokSave: Please tell me how do I pass vector of vectors to my GPU, or initiate a DMA transaction to transfer it to my NIC...

Comment: @AlokSave: But is it possible not to use vector, just like the _macierz_ array was created? And if so, how can it be used as an argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at shengy's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function) for the various ways to pass a 2D array to a function.